# Referencing a revoked object URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have a UI where user loads various files, among them images. The images are listed with a preview thumbnail much like this example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

The gist of it:

```
<input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function handleFiles(e) {

    …

    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    img.height = 60;
    img.onload = function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
    }
    li.appendChild(img);

    …
}
```

My question is in regard to `revokeObjectURL`. It say that

> Set up the image's load event handler to release the object URL since it's no longer needed once the image has been loaded. This is done by calling the `window.URL.revokeObjectURL()` method and passing in the object URL string as specified by `img.src`.

However, if this is done, one can not directly reference the `src` on a second image. As in:

```
other_image.src = thumbnail.src;
```

Is it OK to simply not revoke it? Only revoke it if I dynamically remove the thumbnail?

Or; Is there another, and for some reason better way, to reference the image?

#### Sample code:

```js
const 
  no_files = document.getElementById("no_files"),
  thumbs = document.getElementById("thumbs"),
  preview = document.getElementById("preview")
  ;
  
function handle_files(files)
{
  if (!files.length) {
    no_files.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    no_files.classList.add('hide');
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      thumbs.appendChild(li);
      
      const img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
      /* 
       * Commented out to alow ref of src
       *
      img.onload = function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
      }
      */
      li.appendChild(img);
    }
  }
}
function do_preview (e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'IMG')
    preview.src = e.target.src;
}
thumbs.addEventListener('mouseenter', do_preview, true);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li img {
  max-width: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #987;
}
.images {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 90%;
}
#preview {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.list, .display {
  border: 1px solid #789;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 90%;
}
.list {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.display {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*"  onchange="handle_files(this.files)">
<div class="images">
  <div class="list">
    <p id="no_files">No files selected!</p>
    <ul id="thumbs"></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="display">
    <img id="preview">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Call this method when you've finished using an object URL to let the browser know not to keep the reference to the file any longer. If you need the reference don't call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these blob URLs points to files that come from the user's disk, it's perfectly fine to not revoke it.  They are just direct pointers to the disk, they (almost) don't hold anything in memory.

If they were pointing to some file in memory (e.g fetched or generated using the Blob constructor) then it might be important to revoke them as soon as you won't need them anymore, so that the Blob they point to can be Garbage Collected and the memory they were allocated can be freed. But if you keep a reference to the pointed Blob or if you need them later on, then it would also be perfectly fine to not revoke it, as long as you are sure not to create too many of these.